# When are you a Buddhist?

Tags: lay-buddhism, sangha, western-buddhism

I know labelling people is not in the spirit of Buddhism.  I am for example member of a Buddhist society, not because I'm so eager to be one but because in my country each religious society gets quite some money for having members (and if your not a member,  the church gets the money).

But when do people (not born into a Buddhist country) call themselves Buddhists?

Answer (score 3):

I live in a country where most people are either atheist or christian. Estimates are that between 0.4 and 1% of all people here call themselves a Buddhist.

It's been my experience that there isn't a single agreed upon definition about when you can call yourself a Buddhist. Some people say you are a Buddhist if you consider yourself to be one, others say you need at least several years training from an acknowledged Buddhist teacher. This being said, most people I know (but certainly not all) regard the ceremony of '[taking refuge](http://viewonbuddhism.org/refuge.html)' as the moment when they became a true Buddhist.

Personally I like the view of [Dzongsar Jamyang Khyentse Rinpoche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dzongsar_Jamyang_Khyentse_Rinpoche) who has written a book on the topic called "[What Makes You Not a Buddhist](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590305701)":

> It’s whether you agree with the four fundamental discoveries the Buddha made under the Bodhi tree, and if you do, you can call yourself a Buddhist ([source](http://www.lionsroar.com/what-makes-you-a-buddhist/)).

*Disclaimer: this answer is largely based on [my own answer on a similar question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/2033/408)*